# asm emebed C calling libc functions

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

two years ago and this would work:

```
 int main(int argc,char **argv){
 char f[]="qwestion";
 asm("movq %0,%%rdi\n\t"
 "callq puts\n\t"
 ::"r"(f));
 };
```

but now im trying to call call puts@PLT adding and substracting 
_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_It works only y i add a high level function
call puts at the end of C function
How can it be done standalone?
Tryied everithing gcc -static program.c ,etc

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing calling functions inside inline assembly is a bad idea. With 64-bit code you have to concern yourself with the [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) . You also have to concern yourself with at least marking all the volatile registers as clobbered. When you used `-static` did it compile and link and the program failed to run as expected?

Comment: If you turn on optimizations you also will find more failures. Passing `f` (piinter to a string) as a constraint doesn't guarantee that `f` will be realized into memory (the stack in this case since `f` is a local variable). You'd have to add another dummy constraint `"m"(f)` to force the compiler to make sure `f` is in memory before the template is called.

Comment: As well you can use `"D"(f)` and remove the `movq` in the template instead of using `"r"(f)`

Comment: I'm curious why you need to think about even GOT table ? In assembly code `puts` is just `puts`, not `puts@PLT`. In fact, your code above if not compiled with optimization should work for both dynamic and static linking.

Comment: GOT because not complining  error/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWeinUs.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile con -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: fail on final value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @liliscent This code may not even work with optimizations off. Compiler will generally use the red zone without optimization turned on. This means that static variables will be placed onto the stack (if they are small enough) without adjusting _RSP_. The CALL will place the return value on the stack potentially clobbering the local array `f`. At a minimum you have to consider subtracting 128 from RSP before the call and adding 128 back after the call to avoid that problem.

Comment: Are you sure you get that error when using `gcc program.c -static` ?

Comment: Of course beyond all that you also run the risk of having an unaligned stack when calling _C_ library functions which can cause problems. Stack has to be 16 byte (or 32-byte aligned depending on argument types) at the point of a `call` instruction. This is part of the AMD64 System V ABI specification.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's really an enlightening point. I don't know compiler is allowed to do this, since in assembly code I've read, a `subq` to `rsp` is usually put at the beginning of a function. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Oops in comment above I said `CALL will place the return value on the stack` I meant `return address`

Comment: SOLVED  it was alignment           and $0xfffffffffffffff0,%%rsp before call puts and link against -static